# What configuration might have changed as a result of which all extracted binaries are marked non executable by default?

Tags: permissions, scripts, lubuntu, execute-command

I am using Lubuntu 22.04 OS.

```
abhishek@abhishek:~/test_OS_proj/linux-6.0.19$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               abhishek@abhishek 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           -----------------                                                                   
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64                                                       
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: MS-7A33 3.0                                                                   
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic                                                           
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 23 mins                                                                     
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1942 (dpkg), 7 (snap)                                                     
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.1.16                                                                  
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080                                                               
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Terminal: /dev/pts/0                                                                
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 1800X (16) @ 3.600GHz                                              
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590                                
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Memory: 4377MiB / 32046MiB                                                          
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/                                                                                        
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+                                                                                         
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/                                                                                          
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.                                                                                           
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-                                                                                             
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`                                                                                               
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.                                                                                                   

abhishek@abhishek:~/test_OS_proj/linux-6.0.19$
```

I was playing around with the cpuset subset of the system. I do not know whether it is because of the above or not. But now when I extract the linux kernel from archive, all the files present inside `scripts` folder are marked non executable. I have to now manually do the follow:

```
$ chmod +x linux-6.0.19/scripts/*
```

Or else `make` or `make menuconfig` throws error.

But previously, I did not have to do change the executable permission for the files in the scripts. Just extracting and setting the pwd to the root `linux-6.0.19` directory and doing `make` or `make menuconfig` used to serve the purpose.

I see few other issues popping up in my system which was not there previously. Related to execute permission of various scripts.

What might have changed? Please can you guide me?

Comment: "extract the linux kernel from archive" how exactly? if you are using `tar` there are some default rules about permission preservation depending on whether you are root or not. For an unprivileged user, the current `umask` may be a factor.

Comment: `7z x linux-6.0.19.tar.gz` followed by `7z x linux-6.0.19.tar`

Comment: OK sorry I don't really know anything about how 7z handles these things

Comment: @steeldriver probably the issue was due to 7z way of handling. Using `tar -xf linux-6.0.19.tar.xz` solves the issue